# How to disable browser close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there way to disable browsers close button and it will open after voting my polls. like firefox using JavaScript or jquery? i created an auto open browser using C# for every 10am it will open my intranet web page and i  want all viewers to vote my polls before leaving my page..

Comment: Why would you want to annoy your viewers like that?

Comment: @Keith. Because he can. (but he can't... `:-)`)

Comment: because they are so busy and they dont want to view my news

Comment: @mapet Exactly. If they are busy and don't want to view your news then trying to force them to is very annoying. But luckily the browser/web designers have disallowed this sort of thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

No. It is absolutely impossible for a webpage to prevent users from closing or otherwise leaving it.

The unscrupulous would love to be able to display an unclosable window of rotating adverts to everyone who visited their website.